# The best way to use a DB table as a job queue (a.k.a batch queue or message queue)

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, locking, job-queue

I have a databases table with ~50K rows in it, each row represents a job that need to be done. I have a program that extracts a job from the DB, does the job and puts the result back in the db. (this system is running right now)

Now I want to allow more than one processing task to do jobs but be sure that no task is done twice (as a performance concern not that this will cause other problems). Because the access is by way of a stored procedure, my current though is to replace said stored procedure with something that looks something like this

```
update tbl 
set owner = connection_id() 
where available and owner is null limit 1;

select stuff 
from tbl 
where owner = connection_id();
```

BTW; worker's tasks might drop there connection between getting a job and submitting the results. Also, I don't expect the DB to even come close to being the bottle neck unless I mess that part up (~5 jobs per minute)

Are there any issues with this? Is there a better way to do this?

Note: the ["Database as an IPC anti-pattern"](http://tripatlas.com/Database_as_an_IPC) is only slightly apropos here because

1. I'm not doing IPC (there is no process generating the rows, they all already exist right now) and
2. the primary gripe described for that anti-pattern is that it results in unneeded load on the DB as processes wait for messages (in my case, if there are no messages, everything can shutdown as everything is done)

Comment: Right - bad = synchronous IPC with blocking on a dbms SELECT as a read. You're presumably doing this as a strategy for introducing asynchronicity.

Comment: BTW, if you want to put the reader(s) on a timer, it's useful to have them check infrequently, but if they find work, they can drain the queue before sleeping again.

Comment: Note my edit: if they find no work, they will never find work. But if that were not true...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I've used successfully in the past:

MsgQueue table schema

```
MsgId identity -- NOT NULL
MsgTypeCode varchar(20) -- NOT NULL  
SourceCode varchar(20)  -- process inserting the message -- NULLable  
State char(1) -- 'N'ew if queued, 'A'(ctive) if processing, 'C'ompleted, default 'N' -- NOT NULL 
CreateTime datetime -- default GETDATE() -- NOT NULL  
Msg varchar(255) -- NULLable
```

Your message types are what you'd expect - messages that conform to a contract between the process(es) inserting and the process(es) reading, structured with XML or your other choice of representation (JSON would be handy in some cases, for instance).

Then 0-to-n processes can be inserting, and 0-to-n processes can be reading and processing the messages, Each reading process typically handles a single message type. Multiple instances of a process type can be running for load-balancing.

The reader pulls one message and changes the state to "A"ctive while it works on it. When it's done it changes the state to "C"omplete. It can delete the message or not depending on whether you want to keep the audit trail. Messages of State = 'N' are pulled in MsgType/Timestamp order, so there's an index on MsgType + State + CreateTime.

Variations:
State for "E"rror.
Column for Reader process code.
Timestamps for state transitions.

This has provided a nice, scalable, visible, simple mechanism for doing a number of things like you are describing. If you have a basic understanding of databases, it's pretty foolproof and extensible.

---

Code from comments:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMessage @MsgType VARCHAR(8) ) 
AS 
DECLARE @MsgId INT 

BEGIN TRAN 

SELECT TOP 1 @MsgId = MsgId 
FROM MsgQueue 
WHERE MessageType = @pMessageType AND State = 'N' 
ORDER BY CreateTime


IF @MsgId IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 

UPDATE MsgQueue 
SET State = 'A' 
WHERE MsgId = @MsgId 

SELECT MsgId, Msg 
FROM MsgQueue 
WHERE MsgId = @MsgId  
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
SELECT MsgId = NULL, Msg = NULL 
END 

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: The part described as "The reader pulls one message and changes the state to "A"ctive while it works on it." is the part I'm interested in. How do you do that bit? (aside from that, it looks like mine is the same as yours with out the stuff that isn't needed for my case.)

Comment: Right, that requires multiple SQL statements between BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN.

Immediately following - an SP for pulling the next message - hacked up a bit, I've omitted error trapping since it was written pre-TRY/CATCH.

Comment: -- PART 1

CREATE PROCEDURE GetMessage
    @MsgType VARCHAR(8)
) AS

    DECLARE @MsgId INT

BEGIN TRAN

SELECT TOP 1
    @MsgId = MsgId
FROM    
    MsgQueue
WHERE MessageType = @pMessageType
    AND State = 'N'
ORDER BY 
    CreateTime

Comment: PART 2

IF @MsgId IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN  
 UPDATE MsgQueue  
 SET State = 'A'  
 WHERE MsgId = @MsgId  
  
 SELECT   MsgId,  Msg  
 FROM  MsgQueue  
 WHERE  MsgId = @MsgId  
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
 SELECT MsgId = NULL, Msg = NULL  
END  
COMMIT TRAN

Comment: what if i have to select more than(multiple) one row(s) at a time?
can i update all at same time?

Comment: Assuming you mark them with a common timestamp, or selection-batch id, you can update them all in a single statement, yes. Or use the "A" state described above, and update where state = 'A'.

Answer (score 40):

The best way to implement a job queue in a relational database system is to use [`SKIP LOCKED`](https://vladmihalcea.com/database-job-queue-skip-locked/).

`SKIP LOCKED` is a lock acquisition option that applies to both read/share (`FOR SHARE`) or write/exclusive (`FOR UPDATE`) locks and is widely supported nowadays:

- Oracle 10g and later
- PostgreSQL 9.5 and later
- SQL Server 2005 and later
- MySQL 8.0 and later

Now, consider we have the following `post` table:

[image: post table]

The `status` column is used as an `Enum`, having the values of:

- `PENDING` (0),
- `APPROVED` (1),
- `SPAM` (2).

If we have multiple concurrent users trying to moderate the `post` records, we need a way to coordinate their efforts to avoid having two moderators review the same `post` row.

So, `SKIP LOCKED` is exactly what we need. If two concurrent users, Alice and Bob, execute the following SELECT queries which lock the post records exclusively while also adding the `SKIP LOCKED` option:

```
[Alice]:
SELECT
    p.id AS id1_0_,1
    p.body AS body2_0_,
    p.status AS status3_0_,
    p.title AS title4_0_
FROM
    post p
WHERE
    p.status = 0
ORDER BY
    p.id
LIMIT 2
FOR UPDATE OF p SKIP LOCKED
 
[Bob]:                                                                                                                                                                                                              
SELECT
    p.id AS id1_0_,
    p.body AS body2_0_,
    p.status AS status3_0_,
    p.title AS title4_0_
FROM
    post p
WHERE
    p.status = 0
ORDER BY
    p.id
LIMIT 2
FOR UPDATE OF p SKIP LOCKED
```

We can see that Alice can select the first two entries while Bob selects the next 2 records. Without `SKIP LOCKED`, Bob lock acquisition request would block until Alice releases the lock on the first 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having owner = null when it isn't owned, you should set it to a fake nobody record instead. Searching for null doesn't limit the index, you might end up with a table scan. (this is for oracle, SQL server might be different)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a possible technology change, you might consider using MSMQ or something similar.

Each of your jobs / threads could query the messaging queue to see if a new job was available.  Because the act of reading a message removes it from the stack, you are ensured that only one job / thread would get the message.

Of course, this is assuming you are working with a Microsoft platform.

Comment: I have the data in the DB, when I'm done I need the data in the DB. In my case I see no reason to add another component to the system. (BTW http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

See Vlad's answer for context, I'm just adding the equivalent in Oracle because there's a few "gotchas" to be aware of.

The

```
SELECT * FROM t order by x limit 2 FOR UPDATE OF t SKIP LOCKED
```

will not translate directly to Oracle in the way you might expect.  If we look at a few options of translation, we might try any of the following:

```
SQL> create table t as
  2   select rownum x
  3   from dual
  4   connect by level <= 100;

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open rc for select * from t order by x for update skip locked fetch first 2 rows only;
  5  end;
  6  /
  open rc for select * from t order by x for update skip locked fetch first 2 rows only;
                                                                *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 65:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

SQL> declare
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open rc for select * from t order by x fetch first 2 rows only for update skip locked ;
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

or perhaps try falling back to the ROWNUM option

```
SQL> declare
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open rc for select * from ( select * from t order by x ) where rownum <= 10 for update skip locked;
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

And you won't get any joy.  You thus need to control the fetching of the "n" rows yourself. Thus you can code up something like:

```
SQL> declare
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3    res1 sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  4  begin
  5    open rc for select * from t order by x for update skip locked;
  6    fetch rc bulk collect into res1 limit 10;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score -6):

You are trying to implement de "Database as IPC" antipattern. Look it up to understand why you should consider redesigning your software properly.

Comment: How do you know it's an antipattern in this case, or that the software design is improper? You don't have any context on which to base this comment whatsoever.

Comment: I'd called it a useful pattern for asynchronous IPC. You can configure it to operate like any garden-variety message queue, and they aren't in my experience branded "antipatterns".

Comment: Here's a reference to the antipattern - http://tripatlas.com/Database_as_an_IPC  

The difference is that we're discussing using the database as a message queue, not as a mechanism for processes to interoperate.

Comment: Using a database as a message queue is an anti-pattern. You're going to get lock contention up the ying-yang, and if you're using an MVCC system with multiple workers you're going to end up with nebulous state for any record. You should use a message queue broker like RabbitMQ.

Comment: @jasonjwwilliams not really because using a message broker means that you need to handle distributed transactions - thats why people use outbox pattern, thus database